# Password protect an applet

Tags: applet, passwords

Is there a way to password a protect an applet?

Comment: Please clarify language, framework, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I think too simple. But...

If you want multiple users/passwords
just make a DB that has a table for your users and check them with a database connection ....make a "lock-state" for your applet until you have verified someones identity and after that unlock. That can be as simple as

*just draw this screen and/or use this functionality until username and password matches"

if they match i'll give you more to see...this could be a simple if else construction

if you have enough with one user (easy but not really the way to go)
Just put some values hardcoded in your applet to check if username and password match.